# Error while getting sql output to html

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

SET @tableHTML =
N'<H1>Additions</H1>' +
N'<table border="1">' +
N'<th>f1</th>' +
N'<th>f2</th>' +
N'<th>f3</th>' +
'<tr>' +
CAST ( ( SELECT td = CL.f1, '',
                td = CL.F2, '',
                td = CL.F3, ''                           
          from 
(select * from table2 Where asof = '2/21/2014' and f1= 'abc') CL 
 FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
N'</table>' ;

PRINT @tableHTML
```

My table Structure:

```
f1 varchar,    f2 float,    f3 float

   a           415454        521.215
```

But My in my html output is like

```
f1    f2         f3

a     4.1e201    5.21e001
```

How to get the same integer. float value in the html.

Comment: If you know the max precision you need you can convert to a decimal. Ex: `cast(CL.F2 as decimal(20, 6))`

Comment: you can always cast it with [`STR()` function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx). it is specifically designed to return a string from float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `cast(CL.F1 as decimal(25, 6))`